# setState not setting value in useEffect

Tags: reactjs, typescript, async-await, axios

I'm making an async call inside useEffect. When the promise resolves, I am able to successfully log the data in the response. However, after I set state and index into it, I get an empty array and an error. How come my array did not get set? I am using Typescript.

```
const [codeTemplate, setCodeTemplate] = useState([])
const [code, setCode] = useState("")

useEffect(() => {
    getQuestion({questionName}.questionName)
    .then(resp => {    
      console.log(resp.data.question_template)
      setCodeTemplate(resp.data.question_template)
      console.log(codeTemplate)
      setCode(codeTemplate[0]['boilerplate'])
    })
  }, [])
```

Console output:

```
(3) [{...}, {...}, {...}]
[]
QuestionPage.tsx:79 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'boilerplate')
```

Comment: `setState()` is asynchronous, At the time you `console.log` the state, it's not updated yet. You can try `console.log(codeTemplate)` after `useEffect()` .

Comment: What if I need to index the array before the useEffect function is done? i.e. `var x = codeTemplate[0]`

Comment: Why not use `resp.data.question_template[0]` or `resp.data.question_template[0]['boilerplate']` if you want it inside the `useEffect` ?

Answer (score 0):

setState function in react is asynchronous if you try to console.log after it the results might still not be saved but if you try to console.log after a while (like 1,2 seconds) it will console your results and here is a small code for declaration

```
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import './App.css';
function App() {
  const [user, setUser] = useState([]);
  useEffect(() => {
    let promise = new Promise(resolve => resolve(fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users').then(result => result.json())));
    promise.then(result => setUser({ user: result }));
    console.log(user);
    // it will consile [] empty array
  }, [])

  return (
    <div className='App'>
      <button onClick={() => console.log({ user })}> test</button>
      {/* here when you click the user will exist */}
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

if you want to see the results from setState in class component it used to have a callback function as a second arg, but now it is not in the hook version(useState).

if you are trying to get value out of your response you can
use **setCode()** directly like

```
setCode(resp.data.question_template[0]['boilerplate'])
```

Answer (score 0):

You should replace `setCode(codeTemplate[0]['boilerplate'])` to `setCode(resp.data.question_template[0]["boilerplate"])`, because `useState` hook is asynchronous.

I reworked your `useEffect` and also replaced `Promises chaining` to `Async/Await`, because this writing style is more popular. You can try it:

```
  const [codeTemplate, setCodeTemplate] = useState([]);
  const [code, setCode] = useState("");

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchData = async () => {
      try {
        const resp = await getQuestion({ questionName }.questionName);
        setCodeTemplate(resp.data.question_template);
        setCode(resp.data.question_template[0]["boilerplate"]);
      } catch (e) {
        console.log("error", e);
      }
    };

    fetchData();
  }, []);
```

Answer (score 0):

When the `state` had changed, the re-render begins.
And the `setState()` is asynchronous.
So `console.log(codeTemplate)` in `useEffect()` are always empty array.(its init value)
Move `console.log(codeTemplate)` out of `useEffect()`.

```js
useEffect(
  // ...
,[])

//  Move to here
console.log(codeTemplate);
```

Then you can see the `codeTemplate`'s change logs.

An example (modified from your question)

```js
function App () {
const [codeTemplate, setCodeTemplate] = React.useState([])
const [code, setCode] = React.useState("")

React.useEffect(() => {
    getQuestion("questionName")
    .then(resp => {    
      //  Consider using spread operator [...]
      const temp = resp.data.question_template;
      setCodeTemplate(temp)
      setCode(temp[0]["boilerplate"])
    })
}, [])
  
  //  Set console.log here can see state `codeTemplate`'s changes 
  console.log(codeTemplate)
        
  return <div>
    App:
    <br></br>
    codeTemplate: {codeTemplate.map(x=> x.boilerplate)}
    <br></br>
    code: {code}
  </div>
}

const container = document.getElementById('root');
const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(container);
root.render(
  <App />
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/18.2.0/umd/react.development.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/18.2.0/umd/react-dom.development.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/babel-standalone@6/babel.min.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>

<script>
async function getQuestion (questionName) {
  if(questionName){
    return {
      data: {
        question_template: [{'boilerplate': 'AAA'}, {"boilerplate": "BBB"}]
      }
    }
  }
}
</script>
```